# How to automate routine Microsoft Word operations?

Tags: text, ms-word

For example, I got text document. Like so:

```
At around 6am last Bank Holiday **Monday** I was called by our **Australian** news desk who informed me of the news. Stumbling from my bed to the lounge, still half asleep and with the remnants of an enjoyable **Sunday evening** taking revenge on my skull, I was struggling to process the notion of putting one foot in front of the other let alone news that the world's most **notorious terrorist** had been killed.
```

It is just for example.
Our work is to replace bold words with our own that we take from the paper docs. The operation is very routine, you scroll text, find the word, delete it, type in your new word etc.
I thought maybe there is a way to automate it? Maybe with macros or some other mechanism?
Microsoft word version is 2000. For example I see it like window where it asks: Enter this: - ok - next window - enter this - and in the end it enters all data into new file.

Comment: For future reference, post stuff like this on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It is called [Mail Merge](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can totally use Word Macros to automate using find and replace.. 1) Record a macro. 2) do find and replace 3) stop recording macro 4) look at vb, at a couple of loops if you need, etc. 5) assign macro to function key (it's easy in Excel at least, never had to do with Word)